# Word Ladder Solution in Java using ArrayList

Tags: java, collections

**Word Ladder**

> Given a *start word* and a *goal word*, convert the *start word* to the *goal word* by changing one letter at a time. Each step must also be a valid word.

Is my code modular? I mean are functions are concise, class design etc.? Could someone please review the code and let me know if code is good and if it has some design issues. Any tips on improving the design, and making the code cleaner, change variable names?

Used dictionary at [this URL](http://www.andrew.cmu.edu/course/15-121/dictionary.txt).

```
package test1;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class WordLadder {

    private final HashSet<String> dic= new HashSet<>();
    private final List<Node> nodeQ= new LinkedList<>();
    private final HashSet<Node> visitedNodes= new HashSet<>();
    private final String in;
    private final String target;

    public WordLadder(String i, String t){
        in=i;
        target= t;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        WordLadder wl= new WordLadder("stone","money");
        //WordLadder wl= new WordLadder("stone","chore");
        //WordLadder wl= new WordLadder("stone","choky");
        //WordLadder wl= new WordLadder("charge","comedo");     //takes time ~ 3 mins- seems hardest

        wl.loadDictionary();
        if(!wl.dic.contains(wl.in)||!wl.dic.contains(wl.target)){
            System.out.println("error words not in dic");
        }

        wl.nodeQ.add(new Node(wl.in));

        wl.getPaths();
    }

    private void getPaths(){
        long st= System.currentTimeMillis();
        while(!isMatchFound()){
            Node n= selectNext();
            nodeQ.remove(n);

            addNextWordsToQ(n);

            visitedNodes.add(n);
        }

        System.out.println("nodeQ- \n"+nodeQ);
        System.out.println("visitedNodes- \n"+visitedNodes);

        long end= System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("time taken in sec~ "+ (end-st)/1000);
        System.out.println("time taken in min~ "+ (end-st)/60000);
    }

    private Node selectNext(){
        Node sel= null;
        int minMatch=-1;
        int match;

        for(Node n: nodeQ){
            match=0;
            for(int i=0; i<target.length(); i++){
                if(n.str.charAt(i)== target.charAt(i)) {
                    match++;
                }
            }
            if(match>minMatch){
                sel=n;
                minMatch=match;
            }
        }
//      System.out.println(sel.str+" "+minMatch);
        return sel;
    }

    //Add next possible combinations to the nodeQ
    private void addNextWordsToQ(Node n){
        String s= n.str;
        for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
            String regex= s.substring(0,i)+"."+s.substring(i+1);
            Pattern p= Pattern.compile(regex);
            for(String d: dic){
                Matcher m= p.matcher(d);
                if(!d.equals(s) && s.length()==d.length() 
                        && m.find() && !isNodeVisited(d)){
                    nodeQ.add(new Node(d,n));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Check nodeQ to see if word ladder is solved
    private boolean isMatchFound(){
        for(Node n: nodeQ){
            if(target.equals(n.str)){
                System.out.println(n);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean isNodeVisited(String add){
        for(Node n: visitedNodes){
            if(n.str.equals(add)){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void loadDictionary() throws IOException{
        InputStream is= WordLadder.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("dictionary.txt");
        BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String s= br.readLine();
        while(s!=null){
            dic.add(s);
            s= br.readLine();
        }
    }
}

class Node{
     String str;
     final List<String> path= new ArrayList<>();

    public Node(String str){
        this.str=str;
    }

    public Node(String str, Node parent){
        this.str=str;
        path.addAll(parent.path);
        path.add(parent.str);
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((str == null) ? 0 : str.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Node other = (Node) obj;
        if (str == null) {
            if (other.str != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!str.equals(other.str))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "\n" + str + ", " + path+ "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Performance**

  The most heavy working part of the code seems to be `addNextWordsToQ`; lets focus on it.

  - One immediate observation is that it does a lot of unnecessary work by trying to match *a priori* non-matching words of the wrong length. Sort the dictionary by word length in advance (a small one-time investment), and match only against the relevant section.
  - A `regex` is an overkill. Too many strings are built; the dictionary is traversed too many times (once for each position in the word). The only thing you are really interested in is a Hamming distance between the current word and the candidate word being equal to 1. Hamming distance calculation is as trivial as

    ```
    static private int hammingDistance(String s1, String s2) {
        assert(s1.length() == s2.length();
        int distance = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); ++i) {
            distance += (s1.charAt(i) != s2.charAt(i));
        }
        return distance;
    }
    ```
  - Order of testing conditions is important. If the node is visited, you may omit matching attempt completely.

  That said, I would change the whole thing to

  ```
  private void addNextWordsToQ(Node n) {
      for (String candidate: subdict) {
          if ((!isNodeVisited(d) && (hammingDistance(n.str, d) == 1)) {
              nodeQ.add(new Node(d, n));
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  - Notice that `selectNext` in fact calculates Hamming distance, and the code may now be reused.
  - Speaking of `selectNext`, it also incurs performance penalty. It scans the whole queue each time. You'd be much better off using some sorted collection instead of a linked list. A priority queue comes to mind.

Answer (score 5):

**Style**

- Using braces `{}` for single `if` statements would make your code less errorprone. If you decide to not use them, you should be at least consistent with your style. You are mixing both.
- give your variables some space to breathe.

  > ```
  > while(s!=null){
  > ```

  will be much more readable like

  ```
  while (s != null) {
  ```

**Naming**

- reading `getPaths()` I would expect to **get** something back by calling this method.
- you shouldn't shorten variable names. You are using a lot of single letter names which is ok for a loop iteration counter, but not like you use them. Improving readability will make **Mr.Maintainer** happy.

**Node**

- You should make `str` `final` to show that it isn't changed anywhere.
- In the `hashCode()` method you can remove the `result` variable and just return the result

  ```
  public int hashCode() {
      final int prime = 31;
      return prime + ((str == null) ? 0 : str.hashCode());
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. Is my code modular- I mean are functions are concise, class design etc.

Comment: Because I don't know what `WordLadder` should be, I just took a quick glance at it. Maybe someone else can answer this more thoroughly.

Comment: OK, it is really interesting check out app if you are not busy (not by me)- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.etropa.wordladder&hl=en

Comment: @JavaBeginner I've updated your question description to include what the game is about too...